# How to get the value that a HTML textbox holds

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Value form Textbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            First Name:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="firstname"> Last Name:<input type="text" id="lastname" value="lastname">
```

This is the script which I believe to be causing problems, I am unsure if this is the correct method to use to get the value of the textbox

```
            <script>
                var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname");
                var last_name = document.getElementById("lastname");
            </script>

            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="my_checker(first_name, last_name);">
        </form>
        <script>
            function my_checker(fName, lName)
            {
                alert("Hello " + fname + " " + lname);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the first `script` tag after `body` tag

Comment: You do not read the value

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```js
function my_checker(){
      var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
      alert("Hello " + fname + " " + lname);
}
```

```html
    <head>
        <title>Get Value form Textbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            First Name:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="firstname"> Last Name:<input type="text" id="lastname" value="lastname">
              <p></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="my_checker();">
        </form>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to attach that function to an onSubmit event, in case the user submits the form without clicking?

Answer (score 0):

This one is not the right method but still..
if you want the code has two error first variable you are receiving and trying to alert both are different (fName, lName) / (fname, lname). secondly to access value u need document.getElementById("firstname").value tag

```
<script>
            var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
            var last_name = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        </script>

            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="my_checker(first_name, last_name);">
        </form>
        <script>
            function my_checker(fname, lname)
            {
                alert("Hello " + fname + " " + lname);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you would structure it.

Note that you should use eventListeners instead of inline javascript - and always separate your js from the html... You don't put scripts randomly in your html markup.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Value form Textbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            First Name:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="firstname"> 
            Last Name:<input type="text" id="lastname" value="lastname">
            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">
        </form>
        <script>            
            document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(); // important to stop the form from actually submitting.
              var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
              var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
              alert("Hello " + fname + " " + lname);
            });    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the script should be `var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname").value;`

Comment: yes, but you could do with variable first_name what ever you want. The value is there.